# French press vs simple filter, is French press equipment really necessary?

Tags: equipment, french-press, filter

French press coffee is basically when you pour almost boiling water onto ground beans and then filter them (by pressing the filter handle).

So I wonder why use that contraption at all?
Simply pour the hot water over the beans and then pour them in a glass over a filter.

Is there something I am missing that makes that contraption necessary?

Comment: BTW, normally, you put the grounds in first, then pour the water.

Comment: @MTSan, yes, thank you, I wrote it in the wrong order.

Comment: Almost-boiling is too hot for decent French press, IMHO.

Comment: This is more or less what the Clever dripper does...pour hot water over the grounds, wait, then drain through a filter to the cup or other server. The advantages over French Press: easier clean up, grounds don't sit in the water. And, depending on your taste, fewer sediments/oils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is, no. You don't really need the exact French-press equipment to prepare a drinkable cup of French-press coffee.

However, the equipment is very likely to ease your preparation. Otherwise, you should take care about

- timing
- amount of water (and maybe setting the coffee/water ratio)
- filter-size
- act of filtering quickly and properly

all by yourself to have a decent cup. If you aren't experimenting or looking for adventure I advise you to pay 5 bucks for the equipment.