# How much water should I pour in for blooming process for a french press technique?

Tags: french-press

How much water should I pour in for blooming process for a french press technique?

I put 1 tbsp coffee in a cup. How much water is too much or too little for blooming process for french press technique?

Don't have a plunger.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a plunger? How do you filter it then?

Comment: @avocado1 using a tea strainer

Comment: If you let the grounds settle in the jar you are brewing in you will probably be able to strain it without even needing the tea strainer. It won't help you that much anyways, because the fines are too fine to be strained by it. So better be careful and not use it, than use it without being careful.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** I think this question have a few facets. Also, I think all of them have been discussed before. So, before answering, I advise the users to search for the relevant tag, [french-press](/questions/tagged/french-press) in this case, in the future before asking questions.

---

Having a plunger or not: This has been discussed before. Whether it is strictly required to have the French-press equipment. In theory, no. In practice, it is quite useful. You can see the previous discussion below:

- [French press vs simple filter, is French press equipment really necessary?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/french-press-vs-simple-filter-is-french-press-equipment-really-necessary/3799#3799)

---

How you can prepare a French-press? This has been answered a few times before. There are several answers for different tastes. A quick recipe can be found below:

- [What is the recommended coffee bean to water ratio for drip brewing?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/what-is-the-recommended-coffee-bean-to-water-ratio-for-drip-brewing/2718#2718)

There are detailed explanations here:

- [how to make French Press coffee the right way?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/how-to-make-french-press-coffee-the-right-way)

---

Finally, about the blooming and the French-press technique: Please see the answers in this discussion. Especially, @tsturzl explains the reasons behind blooming neatly.

- [Does the bloom matter in French Press?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/does-the-bloom-matter-in-french-press)

Answer (score 0):

For French Press pre-infusion is not that important since it's a full immersion method. For pour overs the difference is more significant.
However you can pre-infuse for 30s with double the amount of water as you use coffee. So for example if you use 15g of coffee you should put 30g of water.

Pour in the water, give it a quick stir so also the grounds that swim on top get wet, wait 30s and pour in the rest of the water. A good ratio is 100ml of water for each 6g of coffee. For a cup of coffee (250g) you would then need around 15g of coffee (although I personally prefer it slightly stronger).